# Rollback Mechanism For Third Party Services

Tags: java, spring-boot, rollback

I have three different third-party services and I try to call all of them in a single handle method. Also, I want to handle rollback operation. But I'm not sure about implementation. Here is my code:

```
void handle() {
    service1.create();
    callService2OrRollback();
    callService3OrRollback()
}

void callService2OrRollback() {
  try {
      service2.create();
  } catch(Exception e) {
      service1.delete();
      throw e;
  }
}

void callService3OrRollback() {
  try {
      service3.create();
  } catch(Exception e) {
      service1.delete();
      service2.delete();
      throw e;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to implement rollback mechanisms? BTW, I'm using java and spring-boot.